# How to use variable obtained from a parse method in onCreate

Tags: java, parse-platform, parse-android-sdk

I am having lots of trouble with variable and parse Querys. Some of my solutions are to create a method and put parameters into it and call it from the query and insert the values that i need as parameters. but i need to make use of those values in onCreate. When put this variables as Global

```
ParseObject empresa;
    String stringEmpresa;
    String tipoDeEmpresa;
    String tipoEmpresa;
    String role;
```

and the put the values inside the query when I use them on onCreate they are null.

```
public void parseQuery(){

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.include("Empresa");
        query.include("ComercialAsignado");
        query.include("ComercialTallerAsignado");
        query.getInBackground(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId(), new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {
                    queryEmpresa();

                    tipoDeEmpresa = object.getString("tipoDeEmpresa");

                    role = object.getString("Rol");

                    initBottomFromRolUser(role, tipoDeEmpresa);

                    showItemNVFromRol(role, tipoDeEmpresa);

                    initFloatingButton(tipoDeEmpresa);


                }
            }
        });
```

[image: Query method]
I also tried to retrieve the data with another method but it retrieves the wrong data, here is a screenshot. The other problem is that is not retrieving all the columns presented in my user class, this is why

```
tipoEmpresa=user.getString("tipoDeEmpresa");
```

this is null.

Also note that my Rol for demo3 is Administrador, not Usuario.

[image: Current Rol]

Remember setting those global variables inside the done method doesn't let me use these variables in onCreate

Answer (score 1):

Felipe,
the code you posted here does not reflect the one on your screenshot.

Would you please test it with a fixed objectId just so we can know the problem is not coming from ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId()?

Test it like this please:

```
final String objectIdOfUser = "LJ9AongycH";
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground(objectIdOfUser, new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // The query was successful, returns the users that matches
            // the criterias.
            System.out.println(objectIdOfUser + " " + object.getString("Rol"));
            System.out.println(objectIdOfUser + " " + object.getString("tipoDeEmpresa"));
        } else {
            // Something went wrong.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes i did that i have it in the buttom of my class and i call that method in start of my class that worked perfect .. the problem is what i describe i cannot use those variables in onCreate